# How to make debug.log timestamps local time?

Tags: debug, timestamp

I look at the debug.log file a lot while developing, and having all the timestamps in UTC drives me crazy!  How can I get them to display in local time?  I have my php.ini 'date_timezone' value set to 'America/Los_Angeles' already.

Comment: Same problem here.. have you figured out how to do this?

Comment: Nope.  Neither WordPress nor PHP settings seem to have any effect.  :(

Comment: @neoDev, in case you never figured this out, I just posted my answer below with a code snippet that you can use as an alternative

Answer (score 2):

What is the time zone setup in your admin -> settings -> general page? WordPress overrides & kind of disregards php's timezone  & uses this own settings , if haven't set this - default is UTC+0

Update: according to https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/39595 - wordpress has forced this to be UTC

Comment: I have tried both "Los Angeles" and "UTC - 8".  Neither seems to have any effect on the error log timestamp.

Comment: same here, changing it seems to have no effect (WordPress 4.9.2) I even restarted the server...

Comment: Same problem!.. Wordpress 5.3.2 is still using UTC time anyway.. It sucks.. Why wordpress is disregarding settings!?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the debug.log, convert the dates yourself, and display the results in your admin area.

I did this for a plugin I made, but have changed the code slightly to display the debug.log in a custom Dashboard widget so someone else can use it.

It will also highlight lines that contain issues from the functions.php file, as well as an additional keyword through a query string search. The code can be found here:

https://gist.github.com/mrgandy/8b6c198d8abf30d3f4e9def7300cc60c

Answer (score 0):

Just set the preferred timezone in functions.php. That's it.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
```

Change 'Asia/Kolkata' with your preferred timezones. [PHP Official timezone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

[image: Before & after of changes]

It's recommended to use child-theme to preserve changes made in functions.php even after the theme gets updated.